# How do you create a block of fields to a second Profile2 using views?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users

I can create a list of profiles of a specific type. That works great. But what's stumping me is I need a view that has fields that pertain to a specific person. Say for instance you are on Bob's "personal" profile and there is a block that has information for bob's second "business" profile (or any other member's other profiles for that matter). How do I create a block for this profile with relative fields that only populates on demand?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Configuration**

You can use the Views module to access the Profile2 fields.

Below is a quote from [ltiong](http://drupal.org/user/1231168) on [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1114454#comment-5238950) regarding accessing fields from multiple profile types.  The same process applies to accessing a single Profile2 type.

> - 5.1 create View (Show:User)
> - 5.2 add relationship, (User:Profile); give the Identifier a unique name ie 'MainProfile'; select a single checkbox for 'Profile type',
>     in my case 'Main profile';
> - 5.3 add another relationship, (User:Profile); give the Identifier a unique name ie 'EducationProfile'; select the other checkbox for
>     'Profile type', in my case 'Education profile';
> - 5.4 add Fields to view; select Profile2 field items; use Relationship dropdown in 'Configure field' to associate w/ correct
>     relationship;

You can output as a Block, and use the Page URL to retrieve the correct user ID to load. (For your views context)

**Using Code**

You can use the [profile2_load_by_user](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.module/function/profile2_load_by_user/7)(); function to programmatically retrieve Profile2 data.

```
$profile_data = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid);
```

See also: [profile2_load_multiple](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.module/function/profile2_load_multiple/7)()

Comment: Thank you.... I'm a newbie... How do I implement this code... Wouldn't I need arguments, contexts, and relationships???

Comment: I added the configuration method from a post on Drupal.org.  This should allow you to access the fields in a view that can be output as a Block.  I will try to clarify if this is on the right track.

Comment: I did the above and was able to get one block... but I need have any control over which content showed... it was always the first user I created no matter what I adjusted. I will try again and see... will report back in a couple hours if it worked or not.